# How do i install Debian (replacing Ubuntu) without losing data?

Tags: debian, ubuntu

so, now i have ubuntu 22.04.02 lts. I discovered that debian is same as Ubuntu, but lighter. Because i'm dualbooting ms-windows and ubuntu it quite space-consuming, so i really need answer from you guys

P.S Do not tell me ubuntu is better and keep using it.

Comment: safest .. backup, fresh install, restore what you need

Comment: Ubuntu and Debian can be both slim and fat, it's really not useful to install debian to get less – just uninstall (or don't start installing) the stuff you don't need; you need to do that on both Ubuntu and Debian. There's literally no difference there.

Comment: so is there a good debian based linux that is light like 700-1.5 gb?

Comment: That depends on what software you need. Just a minimal system without X (i.e.  text console only)? Sure, that can easily fit in much less than 700MB. Need X plus a window manager or desktop environment, plus a browser or two and libreoffice and lots of other apps? Nope, there's no way that's all going to fit in 1.5GB of disk space. To trim down either Debian or Ubuntu (or any other distro) take a close look at what you currently have installed and compare that with what you actually need. Uninstall any packages you don't need. Then `apt autoremove` to uninstall no-longer-needed needed deps

Comment: i just need a fresh distro with nothing

Answer (score 0):

I have separate `/home`, partition. It does mean you have to know how big. But, makes it easier to install the next OS. Because, replacing the OS does not replace `/home`. I also have a `/home/system` directory that contains `opt` and `usr/local`.

It is possible to get to this state (but broken OS partition: but who cares if you are about to write over it) using a live OS. (backup data before you start)